# position of the object within a photography

Tags: digital

Is it possible for the standard cameras to take a picture of a certain dimension but the object we focus on must respect the exact distances we want from top, left,bottom and right sides ?

I mean, suppose I take a picture of dimension 1000*1000. Does it exist where cameras can be set somewhere so that object taken under this format must respect the dimensions hilighted in this image ?

[image]

Comment: I do not understand the question.  Please edit the question and provide more details.  Thanks,

Comment: @MarkP I edited my question, please let me know if it is still not clear

Comment: Still not clear to me at least. Are you trying to precompute the subject distance necessary for an object of a given size to take up a given amount of the frame at a given focal length?

Comment: You should do this in post processing. What does require some computations is to calculate from how close you can take the picture (or how large you can take the focal length) so that every part of it is still sharp. The F-number should be limited to stay below the value where you get unsharpness due to diffraction. Taking a picture like that will capture as much detail of the object as possible. Then you are free to do whatever post processing you want.

Comment: thank you, but all what I want to know is if cameras can do this automatically (by doing some settings ?) or not ? @CountIblis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us wait untill Terminator takes photographs (not a red video) only then the answer will be yes. In the meantime that should be done by the photographer.

If you need to do that, you need to do your calculations yourself, taking in acount your cameras megapixels, the perspective, your object proportions, do some math, and enter the values at photoshop, resample and crop as necesary.

Comment: thank you very much. I asked the question because I have no knowledge about this even if I read a dozen of articles before asking